„Wirdst" vs „Wirst"? (von „Werden")
Wenn man das wort „wirdst" benutzt, begeht man eigentlich einen Fehler?  Das heißt, es scheint, dass das richtige Wort „wirst" sein soll (zweite Person, Gegenwart von „werden").
Aber ich glaubte, ich habe das Wort „wirdst" irgendwo gehört, und zwar wollte ich es statt „wirst" benutzen.  Wenn ich es nachschlage, sehe ich, dass das Wort ja existiert.  Was dann bedeutet „wirdst" und gibt es irgendwelches Verhältnis mit „wirst"?

"Wenn ich es nachschlage, sehe ich, dass das Wort ja existiert." Wo? Das würde mich sehr überraschen.

Hier kannst du einige Beispiele sehen: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ftsa&q=%22wirdst%22+deutsch&ia=web .  Nach Halvar (unten) sind sie alle falsch.  Ich habe das geahnt und deswegen habe ich hier gefragt.

Reminds me of the only German word with four z letters: Atzventzkranzkerze.

Das Wort "wirdst" gibt es nicht in der deutschen Sprache. Ich weiß auch von keinem Dialekt, in dem es existiert. Wenn jemand das in einem deutschen Satz benutzt hat, war es sicherlich ein Fehler.
Die Beispiele, die z.B. Reverso findet, sind alle falsch.

Danke.  Man weiss von vornherein nicht, dass all diese Beispiele falsch sind.  Ich habe sie gesehen, aber war mir nicht sicher.  Also habe ich hier gefragt. Vielleicht eine alberne Frage, und daher die Downvotes, aber ich wusste nicht, dass Reverso nicht zuverlässig war.
